# php set cookie redirect

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I need a domain example.com redirects to sub-domain a.example.com when I type on the address bar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var city = readCookie('city');
    if(city==null && city==''){
    window.location.href = 'http://' + city + '.example.com';
}
$('#citygo').change(function(){
    var city = $(this).val();
    createCookie('city', city, 28);
    window.location.href = 'http://' + city + '.example.com';
});
});
</script>

<body>
<select id="citygo">
    <option value="0">Select City</option>
    <option value="amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
    <option value="newyork">New York</option>
    <option value="london">London</option>
    <option value="cardiff">Cardiff</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

The cookie on the server side is not holding so the domain cannot remember sub-domain. What am i doing wrong? Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
<?php 
$hour = time() + 50400; 
setcookie(My_Site_Location, $_POST['citygo'], $hour); 

$Loc=$_COOKIE["city"]; 
if(isset($_POST['city'])) 
$Loc=$_POST['city']; 

if (empty($Loc)) { 
    header("Location: http://{$_COOKIE["city"]}.example.com");  
    } else { 
    header("Location: example.com/$Loc.php");  
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `setcookie()` will use the current host as the domain; to override this, you must explicitly specify it:

```
setcookie(My_Site_Location, $_POST['citygo'], $hour, '/', 'example.com');
```

About the domain value, the [manual](http://php.net/setcookie#refsect1-function.setcookie-parameters) says this:

> Older browsers still implementing the deprecated [RFC 2109](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2109) may require a leading `.` to match all subdomains.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced same issue but i solved my problem using the below code in PHP
You are not setting the path and expiration on the cookie. If you have subdirectories it is normally good to set a master cookie that is the root path '/'.

To read your cookie using PHP, try this...

```
$cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
```

...and search the array for your "city" cookie.
Further docs on setting and reading cookies using entirely PHP, check [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

You must call this function before any other code is echoed to the page. (before headers)

This will help you

Comment: Can you explain in more details please? Thanks.